# How to add new record with primary key constraint VB6.0 & SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6

I want to create a message box that will fire whenever the `txt_unit` is equals to the `unit_no` in the database. This is during the insertion of new data in the DB. I'm using VB6 and SQL Server 2005.
This is my code:

```
If txt_unit.Text = 'same unit number that exist in the DB' Then
MsgBox "Duplicate Record", vbCritical, "Duplicate"  
txt_unit.Text = ""  
txt_unit.SetFocus
```

This will save time for the user during data input.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you query the db and fetch the value. Then compare it? Or you could do the comparison within the query itself by passing the textbox's value to it!

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the web for answers, I saw this site that explains the error handling in VB6.
I can finally move on now. Here's the code:

```
On Error GoTo err_CmdAdd_Click

con.Open _
    "Provider = sqloledb;" & _  
    "Data Source=server;" & _  
    "Initial Catalog=database;" & _  
    "User ID=username;" & _  
    "Password=password;"


If img_edit.BorderStyle = 1 Then

Set rs = con.Execute("insert into a_owner values('" & txt_unit.Text & "', " _
& " '" & txt_tower.Text & "'  )")

MsgBox "Record added successfully...", vbInformation

ado1.Refresh

exit_err_CmdAdd_Click:  
Exit Sub

err_CmdAdd_Click:

MsgBox "Duplicate Record!", vbCritical, "Duplicate"
txt_unit.Text = ""  
txt_unit.SetFocus

End If
```